# Flex description causing unmatched rule

Tags: parsing, flex-lexer

My flex description seems to have a catch all before my more specific cases. I'm sure it's a typo on my part but I cant tell which rule is causing the rest of my rules to go unmatched. I believe the likely suspect to be the string description I have created. However I still don't know for sure and am looking for an answer.

branch.l file:

```
%option noyywrap

%{
#include "global.h"
%}

delim           [\t ]
ws              {delim}+
digit           [0-9]
num             {digit}+
alpha           [_a-zA-Z]
identifier      {alpha}({alpha}|{digit})*
relation        [<]|[>]|[>][=]|[<][=]|[=][=]|[!][=]
string          ["][a-zA-Z0-9]*["]

%%

{ws}            {/* skip blanks and tabs */}
{num} {
  tokenval = atoi(yytext);
  return NUM;
}

{identifier} {
  if (strlen(yytext) >= BSIZE) {
    error("compiler error");
  }
  tokensym = lookup(yytext, ID);
  tokensym->count += 1;
  return (int)tokensym->token;
}

"BEGIN"         {return BEGN;}
"IF"            {return IF;}
"THEN"          {return THEN;}
"ELSE"          {return ELSE;}
"GOTO"          {return GOTO;}
"NULL"          {return NUL;}
"READ"          {return READ;}
"PRINT"         {return PRINT;}
"*"             {return '*';}
"+"             {return '+';}
"-"             {return '-';}
"/"             {return '/';}
"("             {return '(';}
")"             {return ')';}
"="             {return '=';}
"."             {return '.';}
"\n"            {lineno++;}
";"             {return ';';}
"END"           {return DONE;}
<<EOF>>         {return DONE;}

{relation} {return RELATION;}
{string} {return STRING;}`
```

And these are the unmatched rules...

```
branch.l:33: warning, rule cannot be matched
branch.l:34: warning, rule cannot be matched
branch.l:35: warning, rule cannot be matched
branch.l:36: warning, rule cannot be matched
branch.l:37: warning, rule cannot be matched
branch.l:38: warning, rule cannot be matched
branch.l:39: warning, rule cannot be matched
branch.l:40: warning, rule cannot be matched
branch.l:51: warning, rule cannot be matched
```

I couldn't figure out easily how to add line numbers. But the warnings are referring to lines BEGIN - PRINT and the ELSE further down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BEGIN` will match both `{identifier}` and `"BEGIN"`. That being the case, flex will (as documented) match the first rule in the file, which `{identifier}`. Consequently, `"BEGIN"` will never be matched.

---

Frankly, I would ditch most (if not all) of those macro definitions. You can use `[[:alpha:]_]` instead of `{alpha}` and `[[:digit:]]` instead of `{digit}` (and, indeed, `[[:alnum:]]*` instead of `({alpha}|{digit})*`). For the most part, using the macros only serves to separate the pattern from the rule action, making the code harder to read (IMHO).

Macros may be useful if you have very complicated patterns or patterns which you use more than once, but that rarely applies.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Your answer helped greatly! Thank you for the included lesson in best practice.